# Ayuda con una transaccion con dapper

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Hola estoy haciendo una transacion usando dapper, pero el detalle es que cuando se marca el error. revierto los cambios con el rollback, pero cuando intento una segunda ejecucion. me indica que el conectionString esta vacia.

```
  using (var cn = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection) {
                cn.Open();
                using (var exec = cn.BeginTransaction()) {
                    try
                    {
                        if (data.Count != 0)
                        {
                            if (txtCot.Text.Length != 0 && cboProv.Text != "")
                            {
                                concurso.CotizacionID = Convert.ToInt32(txtCot.Text);
                                concurso.ProveedorID = Convert.ToInt32(cboProv.SelectedValue.ToString());
                                concurso.Fecha = DateTime.Now;

                                int idx = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>(@"INSERT INTO ConcursoCompra (CotizacionID, ProveedorID, Fecha) VALUES (@CotizacionID, @ProveedorID, @Fecha)
                                                                    select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID;", concurso, exec);
                                for (int i = 0; i < countFila; i++)
                                {
                                    if (dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value != null && dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value != null)
                                    {
                                        concurso.DetallesCompra.Add(new ConcursoCompraDetalles()
                                        {
                                            ConcursoID = idx,
                                            ProductoID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()),
                                            UnidadID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()),
                                            CantidadCotizada = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
                                            CantidadAEntregar = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()),
                                            PrecioCotizado = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvCot.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString())
                                        }
                                        );
                                    }
                                }
                                if (concurso.DetallesCompra.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.Execute("INSERT INTO ConcursoCompraDetalles (ConcursoID, ProductoID, UnidadID, CantidadCotizada, CantidadAEntregar, PrecioCotizado) VALUES (@ConcursoID, @ProductoID, @UnidadID, @CantidadCotizada, @CantidadAEntregar, @PrecioCotizado)", concurso.DetallesCompra, exec);
                                    MessageBox.Show("Concurso NO. " + idx + " Agregado", "Auditorias", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                    cboProv.Text = "";
                                    txtCot.Text = "";
                                    reloadGrid();
                                    concurso.DetallesCompra.Clear();
                                }
                                exec.Commit();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Primero se debe haber seleccionado correctamente\n todos los campos.", "Auditorias", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("La cotización que ingresaste no existe.", "Auditorias", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Asegurate de haber ingresado una cantidad con el formato correcto en la columna de cantidad", "Auditorías ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        exec.Rollback();

                    }
                }
            }
```

En la clase de variables globales se encuentra esto..

```
namespace Auditorias
{
    public static class VariablesGlobales
    {
        private static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection _GlobalConnection;
        public static String UsuarioNombre { get; set; }
        public static String EmpresaNombre { get; set; }
        public static String SucursalNombre { get; set; }
        public static int UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public static int EmpresaID { get; set; }
        public static int SucursalID { get; set; }
        public static int RolID { get; set; }
        public static string Rol { get; set; }
        public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection GlobalConnection
        {
            get
            {
                _GlobalConnection = _GlobalConnection ?? new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
                return _GlobalConnection;
            }

            set
            {
                _GlobalConnection = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al parecer me borra todo mis configuraciones de la conexion cuando indico el rollback.
espero que alguien me ayude, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola el problema lo tienes en esta línea:

```
using (var cn = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection)
```

Cuando termina el bloque using, al objeto GlobalConnection que tienes referenciado en VariablesGlobales se le llama al método "Dispose"
(Aquí lo explica https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Esto es lo que te está "borrando" las configuraciones.
Lo ideal sería cada vez que solicites "VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection" devuelvas siempre una nueva instancia en vez de conservarla como variable miembro.

```
return new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
```

O en caso de necesitar siempre el mismo objeto, no utilices el bloque "Using" sobre la conexión.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.
Saludos

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, cree una nueva instancia de sqlConnection en using(). utilzando connectionString